# It is possible add sections into Jenkins report?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, xunit

I want create sections in JUnit report (displaying in Jenkins) for specify files name or some custom title.
It is possible? and if yes, how?

thanks for feedback

Answer (score 1):

You could maybe achieve this by creating [specific style sheets](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/xUnit+Plugin), or post-process your junit results before the reports are compiled, but without knowing more what you are trying to achieve, why, and where you would configure this task, I find it a bit hard to guide you further.

Comment: junit plugin get necessary field and display with his style. what you mean saying <creating specific style sheets, or post-process>?
I just wont add some title, for example:

slave 1
jUnit results 

slave 2
jUnit results